# Annotating return types for methods returning self in mixins

Tags: python, types, annotations, pycharm, mypy

I am using a builder pattern where most methods on a (big) class return their identity (`self`) and are thus annotated to return the type of the class they're a member of:

```py
class TextBuilder:
    parts: List[str]           # omitted
    render: Callable[[], str]  # for brevity

    def text(self, val: str) -> "TextBuilder":
        self.parts.append(val)
        return self

    def bold(self, val: str) -> "TextBuilder":
        self.parts.append(f"<b>{val}</b>")
        return self

    ...
```

Example usage:

```py
joined_text = TextBuilder().text("a ").bold("bold").text(" text").render()  
# a <b>bold</b> text
```

Now as this class is growing large I would like to split and group related methods up into mixins:

```
class BaseBuilder:
    parts: List[str]           # omitted
    render: Callable[[], str]  # for brevity


class TextBuilder(BaseBuilder):
    def text(self, val: str):
        self.parts.append(val)
        return self
    ...


class HtmlBuilder(BaseBuilder):
    def bold(self, val: str):
        self.parts.append(f"<b>{val}</b>")
        return self
    ...


class FinalBuilder(TextBuilder, HtmlBuilder):
    pass
```

However, I do not see a way to properly annotate the mixin classes' return types in a way that the resulting class `FinalBuilder` always makes mypy believe that it returns `FinalBuilder` and not one of the mixin classes. All that of course assuming I want to *actually* annotate `self` and return types because they may not be inferred from what goes on inside those methods.

I have tried making the mixin classes generic and marking them explicitly as returning a type `T` bound to `BaseBuilder`, but that did not satisfy mypy. Any ideas? For now I am just going to skip all these shenanigans and omit the return types everywhere as they should be properly inferred when using the `FinalBuilder`, but I'm still curious if there is a general way to approach this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the return type to always be what `self` is, just annotate the `self` parameter like so:

```
from typing import List, Callable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseBuilder)

class BaseBuilder:
    parts: List[str]           # omitted
    render: Callable[[], str]  # for brevity


class TextBuilder(BaseBuilder):
    def text(self: T, val: str) -> T:
        self.parts.append(val)
        return self
    ...


class HtmlBuilder(BaseBuilder):
    def bold(self: T, val: str) -> T:
        self.parts.append(f"<b>{val}</b>")
        return self
    ...


class FinalBuilder(TextBuilder, HtmlBuilder):
    pass


# Type checks
f = FinalBuilder().text("foo").bold("bar")

# Mypy states this is type 'FinalBuilder'
reveal_type(f)
```

A few notes:

1. If we don't annotate `self`, mypy will normally assume it's the type of whatever class we're currently contained in. However, it's actually fine to give it a custom type hint if you want, so long as that type hint is compatible with the class. (For example, it wouldn't be legal to add a `def foo(self: int) -> None` to HtmlBuilder since int isn't a supertype of HtmlBuilder.)

   We take advantage of this by making `self` generic so we can specify a more specific return type.

   See the mypy docs for more details: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self
2. I bounded the TypeVar to `BaseBuilder` so that both functions would be able to see the `parts` and `render` fields. If you want your `text(...)` and `bold(...)` functions to also see fields defined within TextBuilder and HtmlBuilder respectively, you'll need to create two TypeVars bound to these more specific child classes.